# SpringBoot jars as a custom module in JBoss EAP 7.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x

I want to create a JBoss EAP custom module for SpringBoot jars and use this custom module across different war deployments in JBoss. This execrise is to reduce the size of war files (by removing spring boot jars from war file) as we move all common jars to a custom module.

We want this to do as we have multiple springboot application wars to deploy in JBoss EAP7.0.

Is this possible to do in JBoss and SpringBoot?
Please shed some light here.

Comment: I'm not a SpringBoot expert, but isn't the concept of SpringBoot to be a self-containing runnable JAR?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to know that Spring Boot is NOT supported in JBoss EAP.
It is not recommended to use Spring Boot in Jboss EAP, although it can be packaged in a war deployment.
Running Spring Boot inside a container, may create several conflicts! For example, a JAX-RS service could be published twice!

Comment: Yes. I agree that Spring Boot and JBoss conflict together. Like JPA, REST etc.. but would it even be possible to deploy spring boot war (excluding bundled tomcat) in JBoss deployment folder.

Comment: I am able to deploy spring boot jars as custom module and run the app by excluding the jpa, resteasy subsystems. But getting errors while trying to create entity classes and create transactions.